# how to pass a xsl variable value to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, xslt

i am trying to pass an xsl variable value to a javascript function.

My xsl variable

```
<xsl:variable name="title" select="TITLE" />
```

i'm passing the value like this

```
<input type="button" value="view" onclick="javascript:openPage('review.html?review=$title')" />
```

i have tried the above code in different possible ways but i gets errors.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                    function jsV() {
                    var jsVar = '<xsl:value-of select="TITLE"/>';
                    return jsVar;
                    }
                </script>

                <input type="button" value="view" onclick="javascript:openPage('javascript:jsV()')" />

I also tried 

<input type="button" value="view" onclick="javascript:openPage('review.html?review='\''
    +$title+'\')" />
```

Is there alternative way or am i not doing it right?

Comment: You are not "passing the value of the XSLT variable to the Javascript function". The XSLT is not calling the Javascript. It is generating HTML with embedded Javascript. You need to understand this processing model!

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much. I'm not sure if its possible to change the question's title, wish i could though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot about {}:

```
<input type="button" value="view" onclick="javascript:openPage('review.html?review={$title}')" />
```

Comment: it doesn't show any value. Anything inside the curly brackets doesnt appear.

Comment: thank you very much.. works fine!... i was playing with the variable right before i tested your code. i made some changes and i forgot about it, thats why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a working example how to do this:

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <xsl:variable name="vTitle" select="TITLE"/>

     <input type="button" value="view"
     onclick="javascript:openPage('review.html?review={$vTitle}')" />
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (no XML document was provided!):

```
<contents>
 <TITLE>I am a title</TITLE>
</contents>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<input type="button" value="view" 
 onclick="javascript:openPage('review.html?review=I am a title')"/>
```

**Explanation**: Use of **[AVT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#attribute-value-templates)** (Attribute Value Templates).

Answer (score 3):

It is also possible to access xsl variable from a JavaScript code in the same file by doing the following:

`<xsl:variable name="title" select="TITLE"/>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getTitle() {
        var title = <xsl:value-of select="$title"/>;
        return title;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: how would you go about escaping quotes if said $title had tilda's, single AND double quotes?