# How to pass XSL variable in to a Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, xslt

Below is my sample XSL file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                //<![CDATA[
                function showHide(elementid){
                    if (document.getElementById(elementid).style.display == 'none'){
                        document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = '';
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById(elementid).style.display = 'none';
                    }
                }
                //]]></script>
                <!-- Inserting pie chart  -->
                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                //<![CDATA[
                google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
                google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
                function drawChart() {
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                        ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
                        ['Work',     11],
                        ['Eat',      2],
                        ['Commute',  2],
                        ['Watch TV', 2],
                        ['Sleep',    7]
                    ]);

                    var options = {
                        title: 'My Daily Activities'
                    };

                    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                }
            //]]></script>
            <!--Finishing pie chRt -->
            </head>
            <body>
                <h2>eBuilder Automation Test Suite-Summary</h2>
                <div id="chart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#808080">
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Total TCS</th>
                        <th>Passed</th>
                        <th>Skipped</th>
                        <th>Errors</th>
                        <th>Failures</th>
                        <th>Pass Rate</th>
                        <th>Tot Time Taken</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="testsuite">
                        <xsl:variable name="PassCount">
                            <number>
                                <xsl:value-of select="(@tests - @skipped - @errors - @failures)"/>
                            </number>
                        </xsl:variable>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@tests"/>
                            </td>

                            <td bgcolor="#32CD32">
                                <xsl:value-of select="(@tests - @skipped - @errors - @failures)"/>
                            </td>
                            <td bgcolor="#FFFF00">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@skipped"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="@errors"/>
                            </td>
                            <td bgcolor="#FF0000">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@failures"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <font color="red">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="(msxsl:node-set($PassCount)/number) div @tests * 100"/>%
                                </font> 
                            </td>
                            <td bgcolor="#008000">
                                <xsl:value-of select="@time"/>
                            </td>
                            <!--xsl:value-of select="@failures div @tests *100"/-->
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want to pass the XSL variable `PassCount` like that below:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
          ['Work',     passcount],
          ['Eat',      2],
          ['Commute',  2],
          ['Watch TV', 2],
          ['Sleep',    7]
        ]);
```

Is there any smart way to do this?

Comment: Hope some one will Help Me pls !

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166994/how-to-pass-a-xsl-variable-value-to-a-javascript-function

Comment: Hi Friend Matpol,Tx for the help.But its not the solution. :-(

Comment: passcount is in a loop? is that why is doesn't work?

Comment: hi matpol,yep its in a loop is there a way to access it then ?

Comment: I don't know but that maybe why the solution in the link doesn't work - I would guess the the function needs to be called more than once as the value could change in the loop.

Comment: Ok tx Friend ! Cheers

Comment: Any one else can help me ?

Comment: Are you saying you wish to display a google chart of your "testsuite" results? It would help if you showed a sample of the XML you are working with. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Tim and matpol,at last i found the issue as u said matpol.i'm calling the variable out from the loop thats why it was faild.any way tx a lot for your valuable time Tim and matpol ! best rgds Lahiru .KIT !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I answer to your question (I not really sure, but anyway)

There should be no problem to generate javascript with xslt, if you don't use CDATA.
Than you can use xsl:value-of to put xslt var values at any position you like.
But without CDATA you have to escap some chars (<,&) in your javascript code.

```
 'Work',     <xsl:value-of select="(msxsl:node-set($PassCount)/number)/> ],
```

or

```
var passcount = <xsl:value-of select="(msxsl:node-set($PassCount)/number)/>;
....
['Work',     passcount],
```

Comment: Hi Hr_117,i found the issue.its because of calling a variable out from a loop.any way thank you tooo for your great effort.KIT .. Lahiru

Comment: can some one give an answear for this theard pls.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16568531/test-suite-bypass-some-tests